How to use HTML5 instead of form helpers -- Using Select2 JS with "acts-as-taggable-on" gem
I am using the acts-as-taggable-on gem as well as the select2.js library.
My community_resource.rb looks like the following:
class CommunityResource < ApplicationRecord
  acts_as_taggable_on :recovery_tags
end

My views/community_resources/_form.html.erb view looks like the following:

In my views/community_resources/_form.html.erb file my (1) traditional form.textfield is written as follows:
 <div class='form-group'>
    <%= form.label :recovery_tag_list %>
    <%= form.text_field :recovery_tag_list, value: @community_resource.send(:recovery_tag_list).to_s %>
 </div>

My (2) Select2.js form field (that does not currently save on submit that I am trying to get to work) is written as follows:
<select class="form-control js-example-basic-multiple" multiple="multiple">

    <%# Loop through all recovery_tag values %>
    <% for tag in ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.for_context(:recovery_tags) %>

      <%# If the the tag is listed in the current @community_resource, output as a "selected" option %>
      <% if @community_resource.send(:recovery_tag_list).include? tag.name %>
      <option selected="selected"><%= tag.name %></option>
      
      <%# Else output tag's name as an unselected option %>
      <% else %>
      <option><%= tag.name %></option>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>

</select>

If helpful here is the whole view: Git gist of views/community_resources/_form.html.erb
I am initializing the Select2 selection element with (which works great)
 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.js-example-basic-multiple').select2({  });
    });
  });

My CommunityResource controller if helpful:
class CommunityResourcesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_community_resource, only: %i[ show edit update destroy ]

  # GET /community_resources or /community_resources.json
  def index
    @community_resources = CommunityResource.all
  end

  # GET /community_resources/1 or /community_resources/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /community_resources/new
  def new
    @community_resource = CommunityResource.new
  end

  # GET /community_resources/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /community_resources or /community_resources.json
  def create
    @community_resource = CommunityResource.new(community_resource_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @community_resource.save
        format.html { redirect_to @community_resource, notice: "Community resource was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @community_resource }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @community_resource.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /community_resources/1 or /community_resources/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @community_resource.update(community_resource_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @community_resource, notice: "Community resource was successfully updated." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @community_resource }
      else
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @community_resource.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /community_resources/1 or /community_resources/1.json
  def destroy
    @community_resource.destroy!

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to community_resources_path, status: :see_other, notice: "Community resource was successfully destroyed." }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_community_resource
      @community_resource = CommunityResource.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def community_resource_params
      params.require(:community_resource).permit(:name, :hours_of_operation, :phone, :address, :website, :information, :recovery_tag_list)
    end
end

How can I write my Select2 element that presently only outputs my recovery resource tags, so that it saves selected options of recovery resource tags on submitting the form to :recovery_tags? Maybe the real question I'm trying to ask is how can I use straight HTML instead of form helper.

just put html to view, add id and name for your select

@AntonBogdanov ugh! so close. it definitely changes on submit, but instead of assigning :recovery_tags all selected tags, it only assigns it the value of the most recently selected one. This is definitely the right direction though. thank you for your help.
